# loggback SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy not roll and not move log file to archive

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I create loggback.xml woth thos appender:

```
<appender name="ROLLING-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!--<file>logs/nfp-server.log</file>-->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>D:/logs/archived/log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- each file should be at most 100MB, keep 60 days worth of history, but at most 20GB -->
      <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>20MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>



<springProfile name="local">
    <logger name="nfp" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ROLLING-FILE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="prod">
    <logger name="nfp" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ROLLING-FILE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
```

and in spring propery:

```
#loging
logging.file=D:/logs/nfp-server_local.log
```

I want each log file > 10KB move to archive. But when I start server in `D:/logs` I have this:

```
-logs
  -nfp-server_local.log (int this file all logs, 48KB)
  -archived
   -log_2018-04-02.0.txt (0 byte)
```